# Изображение в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Сайт с движком WP. Стоит плагин Fotorama, который делает из обычной галереи wp, красивую и настраиваемую. В последнее время возникла необходимость добавлять изображения в записи таким образом, что бы эти изображения не попадали в галерею. То-есть вставить изображение где-то в середине поста, но при этом не добавлять его в галерею (что бы два раза не повторялось одно и то же изображение). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если у Вас уже есть картинка в галерее, то незачем ее выгружать еще раз. Просто при добавлении в пост, выберите вкладку "Библиотека файлов", найдите нужную картинку и нажмите "вставить"

Comment: Ну так мне не надо что бы изображение было в галереи! Если я с библиотеки файлов вставляю картинку, то она и в посте будет, и в галереи.

Comment: Или используйте сторонний фото-хостинг или создайте вручную папку images, заливайте в нее файлы по ftp и используйте при вставке прямую ссылку на них.
А лучше пересмотрите настройки своего плагина Fotorama, имхо это не правильно, что абсолютно все файлы из медиа-библиотеки крутятся в галерее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копируй прямую ссылку на необходимое изображение, вставляеш вместо слова ссылка <img src="ссылка" alt=""/> и потом это вставляеш куда тебе надо, только в редакторе текста.